# Spring boot report 404 error when using @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a beginner of Spring Boot.

I've just wrote a controller, code is here.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello Name!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "hello " + name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then when I visited "localhost:8080", I got the right page.
But when I visited "localhost:8080/hello/someName", I got the 'Whitelabel Error Page'.

What's wrong with my code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `@PathVariable("name") String name`. and use `@ResponseBody` annotation at hello method.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String hello(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return "hello " + name;
    }
```